# Convert quaternions between two coordinate systems where x axis becomes -x

Tags: quaternions

How to estimate new quaternion when x axis becomes -x ?

In short, I need to estimate the new quaternion when rotation around y becomes 180-y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if angle around y is 30 degrees, around x=20 degrees, and around z is z = 70 degrees then around y should become 180-30 degrees  because x becomes -x

In Quaternions:
The new y in -x should be (180-30)*pi/180 and its quaternions are found as follows (original in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles but for different coordinate system)

```
        a = 180-30; //180-30;

        ax = 20 * Math.PI/180;
        ay = a * Math.PI/180;
        az = 70 * Math.PI/180;

        t0 = Math.cos(ay * 0.5);  // yaw
        t1 = Math.sin(ay * 0.5);
        t2 = Math.cos(az * 0.5);  // roll
        t3 = Math.sin(az * 0.5);
        t4 = Math.cos(ax * 0.5);  // pitch
        t5 = Math.sin(ax * 0.5);

        t024 = t0 * t2 * t4;
        t025 = t0 * t2 * t5;
        t034 = t0 * t3 * t4;
        t035 = t0 * t3 * t5;
        t124 = t1 * t2 * t4;
        t125 = t1 * t2 * t5;
        t134 = t1 * t3 * t4;
        t135 = t1 * t3 * t5;

        x = t025 + t134;
        y =-t035 + t124;
        z = t034 + t125;
        w = t024 - t135;
```